# Make HTML load all assets and scripts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loading

I'm pretty new to web development, and we have a school project where we need to create a web shop with three different html pages and some javascript.

I implemented some jQuery as well, add a preloader and stuff. During development i used some VS code extensions like Live Server and Browser Sync.

The problem I'm having now is that i need to send my project to the professor but when i click to open my html document without hosting it on local host (so basically it opens in my browser with the path of something like C://Users/Desktop.....) it doesnt load the assets and the jQuery preloader never finished because the other pages never load.

The link to my code is: https://github.com/DzambaTz/WebShop

I think the problems is that i set some of the images as backgrounds of some divs and now they dont want to load.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: What does your `console` say?

Comment: Completly empty

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem just by correcting paths to my individual assets, scripts etc.

i was using:

```
src="/assets/image.png"
```

instead of:

```
src="./assets/image.png"
```

Correcting that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Note that dynamically loading assets with JavaScript (XHR/`fetch()`) in a HTML file opened in the browser is not possible.

Comment: I wasn't trying to do that, it just wasn't clear to me (and still isn't) why the assets wouldn't load without the dot in front of their path

Comment: That's because a relative URL starting with `/` indicates an absolute URL, so it would resolve to `C:\assets\image.png` or something like that.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check paths of assets(images, Jquery preloader and all). Jquery preloader is not finishing because it is not getting right path. I think you have given paths based on localhost and without localhost they are not showing.